# How can I save all the details of a Neural Network model?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I trained a `neural network model` and saved the model as `'.h5'`.Now
 I want to fetch all the details of the model. The `training loss,val loss,train acc,val acc`,`number of layer,number of neurons.`

How can I save all these information in a file?

I can save as `Json` using to_json method,but it only gives architecture 
 and neurons used.If I need `the loss and accuracy`, I have to further load the model and use `model.evaluate`.

What can I do so that I can save all the details in one file, so that I can refer later,without a python program (preferably as a text).

I researched and got

```
with open('/trainHistoryDict', 'wb') as file_pi:
        pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)
```

But this is a again a `pickle file`,which I need to load and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details such as loss, accuracy etc. are not part of the model, so it is not surprising that they are not saved as such. What you should do is assign a variable to your `model.fit`, and then save it as a CSV file.

Example:

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

hist.history
# result:
{'acc': [0.9165000000317891,
  0.9742000000317892,
  0.98055,
  0.9830833333015442,
  0.9860833333651224],
 'loss': [0.2732362467487653,
  0.08818577744960784,
  0.0647057895908753,
  0.05435932712952296,
  0.046362959186236063],
 'val_acc': [0.9793, 0.9863, 0.9884, 0.9892, 0.9903],
 'val_loss': [0.06013948693200946,
  0.03918295648135245,
  0.03277417989484966,
  0.03275903527000919,
  0.029347733918437733]}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hist.history)
print(df)
# result:
   val_loss  val_acc      loss       acc
0  0.060139   0.9793  0.273236  0.916500
1  0.039183   0.9863  0.088186  0.974200
2  0.032774   0.9884  0.064706  0.980550
3  0.032759   0.9892  0.054359  0.983083
4  0.029348   0.9903  0.046363  0.986083

# save to CSV (without the index):
df.to_csv('history.csv', index=False)
```

After which, inspecting `history.csv` with a text editor, you get

```
val_loss,val_acc,loss,acc
0.06013948693200946,0.9793,0.2732362467487653,0.9165000000317891
0.03918295648135245,0.9863,0.08818577744960784,0.9742000000317892
0.03277417989484966,0.9884,0.0647057895908753,0.98055
0.03275903527000919,0.9892,0.05435932712952296,0.9830833333015442
0.029347733918437733,0.9903,0.046362959186236063,0.9860833333651224
```